# Magento 2: I want to get product id from getCartItems function in minicart.js

Tags: magento2, knockoutjs, mini-cart, knockout

Here is the function in minicart.js

```
getCartItems: function () {
            var items = this.getCartParam('items') || [];
            console.log(items);
            // want to get product id from items here
            items = items.slice(parseInt(-this.maxItemsToDisplay, 10));
            return items;
        }
```

Items are showing JSON array in console with all mini cart items data. But I am not able to get only product IDs from that.

Does anyone have any idea for the same?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **undescore each function** to get product id from items.

```
_.each(items, function (item, key) {
    console.log(item.product_id);
}, this);
```

So you final code looks like:

```
define([
    'uiComponent',
    'jquery',
    'underscore'
], function (Component, $, _) {

    ...
    ...

    getCartItems: function () {
        var items = this.getCartParam('items') || [];

        _.each(items, function (item, key) {
            console.log(item.product_id);
        }, this);

        items = items.slice(parseInt(-this.maxItemsToDisplay, 10));

        return items;
    },

    ...
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much @prince.I am checking and will update you

Comment: Message: this.getCartParamUnsanitizedHtml is not a function Please check this

Comment: Please correct your code  var items = this.getCartParam('items') || [];(add this line) then I will mark correct

Comment: @Shomita May be this is your customization :) I used the default Magento minicart file. Code updated. Thank you!

Comment: I also need to add a check to match product ids. If this product id then needs to show pop up.

Comment: @Shomita Please ask another question about another query to make this simple answer queue.